# Filter pandas dataframe, display in tkinter/pandastable

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I am trying to create an application which involves displaying a medium-sized pandas dataframe. I'm using pandastable and tkinter for my user interface. Part of what I want the user to be able to do is select a filter from a combobox and then have only matching rows display.

Below is a simplified but complete version of the code I'm trying to employ. I create a class which has the core UI code in it. Initially everything looks great. I created a test button function inside my class (change_df) that creates a dummy column, that works fine. I have another function inside the class (change_df_combo) that does successfully filter the dataframe, but it doesn't display onscreen. I.e., I can print the df or export it and it has filtered. However that doesn't show up on screen.

I assume somehow my class or tkinter itself isn't looping right, but for the life of me I can't figure it out! Any thoughts?

```
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import numpy as np
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from pandastable import Table, TableModel

class UserInterface(Frame):
    # Launch the df in a pandastable frame
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        global ui_df
        global pt
        ui_df = pos_df
        self.parent = parent
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.main = self.master
        #self.main.geometry('800x600+0+0')
        f = Frame(self.main)
        f.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(E, W))
        screen_width = f.winfo_screenwidth() * 0.8
        screen_height = f.winfo_screenheight() * 0.7
        self.table = pt = Table(f, dataframe=ui_df, height = screen_height, width = screen_width)
        pt.show()
        return

    def change_df(self, col_val_input):
        #Responds to button
        ui_df['Test col'] = col_val_input
        pt.show()

    def change_df_combo(self, event):
        #Responds to combobox, supposed to filter by 'Sec_type'
        combo_selection = str(combo_box.get())
        ui_df = pos_df[pos_df['Sec_type'] == combo_selection]
        pt.show()

#Create dataframe
pos_data = {'Location' : ['Denver', 'Boulder', 'Phoenix', 'Reno', 'Portland',
'Eugene', 'San Francisco'], 'Sec_type' : ['mbus', 'mbus', 'vmus', 'caus',
'vmus', 'mbus', 'mbus']}
pos_df = pd.DataFrame(data = pos_data)

#Launch Tkinter basics
root = Tk()
root.title("S test...")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

ui_display = UserInterface(mainframe)

#'Test' button, this works fine
col_val_input = 'It worked!'
test_button = ttk.Button(mainframe, text = 'Test', command= lambda: ui_display.change_df(col_val_input))
test_button.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(W))

#Combobox, works to just show choice, but not to filter
combo_choices = ['mbus', 'vmus', 'caus']
choice = StringVar()
combo_box = ttk.Combobox(mainframe, textvariable=choice)
combo_box['values'] = combo_choices
combo_box.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=(W))
combo_box.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', ui_display.change_df_combo)

root.mainloop()
```

Edit to add:
Changed imported df to a toy df for testing purposes

Comment: You might want to include a sample of the Excel file. Otherwise, we can't run your code which makes it harder to debug. A screenshot should work.

Comment: @slightly_toasted: embedded the dataframe in the file to make testing easier

Comment: Tkinter is looping as expected, however your change_df_combo method is simply storing the filtered df in a variable. You need to add code at the end of the method that clears the original data and displays the filtered data.

Comment: Can you elaborate? If I print(ui_df) it looks the way I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I came up with something that works. Not sure it is the most pythonic code ever written but here it goes: (posting just the class segment)

```
class UserInterface(Frame):
    # Launch the df in a pandastable frame
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        global ui_df
        ui_df = pos_df
        self.parent = parent
        self.refresh_df(df = ui_df)

    def refresh_df(self, df):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.main = self.master
        f = Frame(self.main)
        f.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(E, W))
        screen_width = f.winfo_screenwidth() * 0.8
        screen_height = f.winfo_screenheight() * 0.7
        self.table = pt = Table(f, dataframe=df, height = screen_height, width = screen_width)
        pt.show()
        return

    def change_df(self, col_val_input):
        #Responds to button
        ui_df['Test col'] = col_val_input
        self.refresh_df(df=ui_df)

    def change_df_combo(self, event):
        #Responds to combobox, supposed to filter by 'Sec_type'
        combo_selection = str(combo_box.get())
        ui_df = pos_df[pos_df['Sec_type'] == combo_selection]
        ui_df['Test col combo'] = combo_selection
        self.refresh_df(df=ui_df)
```

Comment: hi Tom, I like very much this solution but I seem unable to make it work on py3.7 with matplotlib dependencies. how does it work for you?

Comment: cannot import matplotlib.pyplot. I saw this is a known issue with py3.7